Completeness for existential second-order logic
I find in this link that existential second-order logic is compact.
On the other hand, I find in this link that existential second-order logic is not complete. Here is a quote:

A "naturally occurring logic" that also serves to show that (2) (compactness) does not imply (1) (completeness) is the existential fragment of second order logic; its compactness follows from the usual proofs of compactness of first order logic [including the ultraproduct proof], but its set of valid sentences is known to be co-r.e., but not r.e.

Is there are reference for this result?

The quoted statement is incorrect (and has now been corrected): the set $X$ of ESO validities is neither r.e. nor co-r.e.

$X$ is not co-r.e. since the set of first-order validities reduces to it, and the latter is r.e.-complete.

To see that $X$ is not r.e. either, let $\varphi$ be a first-order sentence in the language of arithmetic and let $\psi$ be the ESO sentence (also in the language of arithmetic) saying "There is some set $S$ such that either the (finitely many, first-order) axioms of Robinson arithmetic do not all hold, or $\varphi$ holds, or $S$ is a proper subset of the universe containing $0$ and closed under successor." This ESO sentence is a validity iff $\varphi$ is true in $\mathbb{N}$, since the only way for $\psi$ to be false is for the universe to be (isomorphic to) $\mathbb{N}$ and for $\varphi$ to fail in that universe. Consequently, the set of ESO validities is not even arithmetically definable, let alone co-r.e. (if you're not familiar with this sort of connection between arithmetic definability and complexity, look up both Tarski's undefinability theorem and Post's theorem).


I don't know a source for the second bulletpoint above; I believe it is folklore.
